# string.AsSpan() vs implicit cast operator peformance in .NET for ReadOnlySpan<char>

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-standard-2.0, ref-struct

Since .NET version something we now have an implicit cast from `string` -> `ReadOnlySpan<char>`. This means that if a function accepts a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, we can just pass it a string and the "conversion" will happen automatically.
This implicit operator is not available in .NET Standard 2.0 nor in .NET Framework though... We are working with all three :)

Basically I have this field in my `ref struct`

```cs
private readonly ReadOnlySpan<char> _defaultDelimiters = new[] { ' ', ';' };
```

I use this field every time a function called `Read()` is called. The alternative would be to remove this field and put a `stackalloc` inside `Read()`. But I do not know if that is wise or not

To make my .NET code compliant with .NET Standard 2.0 and Framework I could simply add `.AsSpan()` calls to my strings. This is however "unnecessary" in .NET (Core) but my question is: Is it also performance wise worse? Or do the `.AsSpan()` extension and the implicit operator perform the same operation behind the scenes anyway?

Comment: Q1: Have you considdered making a POC, have it compile for the different Frameworks and look at the lowered code or even the IL Code? I would _guess_ the result should be pretty similar.

Comment: Please don't ask 3 questions in one post.

Comment: *"would it be better to put this small Span on the Stack using stackalloc?"* `Span<T>` is a `ref struct` - it's already going on the stack.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes the Span of course will always be on the stack but the memory it is pointing to won't. So my question was if it would be better to allocate my chars on the Stack, using stackalloc rather than have them on the heap in a field. I would need to alloc everytime my function is called

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any code, but if you're passing a string to your `readonly ref struct` constructor and storing in the struct a `Span<char>` for that string, it will NOT be allocating anything extra on the heap. The string passed to the struct's constructor will already be on the heap, of course.

Comment: Basically I have this field in my ref struct: private readonly ReadOnlySpan<char> _defaultDelimiters = _defaultDelimiters = new[] { ' ', ';' };
I use this field every time a function called Read() is called. The alternative would be to remove this field and put a stackalloc inside Read(). But I do not know if that is wise or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **As you can see** from [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cbc501ca196371572c38f8d12a66969864d99c08/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs#L361), the following code is executed for the `implicit` operator:

   ```cs
   public static implicit operator ReadOnlySpan<char>(string? value) =>
           value != null ? new ReadOnlySpan<char>(ref value.GetRawStringData(), value.Length) : default;
   ```

   The [extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cbc501ca196371572c38f8d12a66969864d99c08/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MemoryExtensions.cs#L98C1-L104C10) does this

   ```cs
   public static ReadOnlySpan<char> AsSpan(this string? text)
   {
       if (text == null)
           return default;

       return new ReadOnlySpan<char>(ref text.GetRawStringData(), text.Length);
   }
   ```

   So effectively the exact same code. There is absolutely no difference in performance between these. (Possibly a small difference in branch prediction due to the opposite order of the conditions).
2. **No, there is no heap allocation.** A `Span` and a `ReadOnlySpan` are `ref struct` so they *can't* be allocated on the heap even if you tried (like boxing them), it's not allowed.
3. Assuming the `char` array is `static` (or a `string` is coming from a constant value), probably **you are already using** the most efficient allocation method. It doesn't need to reserve any stack space, it can just take a `Span` off the existing array.
   Whereas `stackalloc` means you need to copy the data into it every time. And `stackalloc` can also have serious implications when used in a loop, often causing a stack overflow.
   If the `char` array is not static (eg you are feeding `new[]` straight into the initializer/constructor) then that is going to be even more inefficient. Keep the array `static` in a separate field, or just use a constant `string` value.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Exactly what I wanted to hear. My char array however is not static, but it is readonly. Making it static is not possible as Fields of ReadOnlySpan<char> seemingly MUST be instance fields. So I basically instantiate it like this, for every instance of my struct: private readonly ReadOnlySpan<char> _defaultDelimiters = _defaultDelimiters = new[] { ' ', ';' }; which may not be the best...

Comment: You can make the array itself `static`. Eg `private static readonly char[] _defaultDelimitersArray = new[] { ' ', ';' }; private readonly ReadOnlySpan<char> _defaultDelimiters = _defaultDelimiters = _defaultDelimitersArray;` although I would probably go for a `string` instead as then you don't need another field. See edit. So the best method is probably `private readonly ReadOnlySpan<char> _defaultDelimiters = _defaultDelimiters = " ;";`

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip. Though how would I need only one field with string? I would then get `ReadOnlySpan<char> _defaultDelimiters = " ;"; ` but won't that cause a new string allocation for every instance of the struct? As the string is not explicitly static, or will .NET magic fetch it from the string pool every time?

Comment: Yes, magic. It's called String Interning https://ericlippert.com/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/ all string constants in a library by default refer to the same instance.

Comment: Cool! I recall reading something about this yes. I may introduce it as a private const string field though. .NET Standard 2.0 and Framework forces me to initialize all non static field (ReadOnlySpan) in constructor... in .NET it is ok to do inline. For clarity I may use const field as I have two constructors which should set this